# Runtime error when set margin to text block in flowdocument

Tags: c#, wpf, runtime-error

Runtime error while setting margin of a text block in c# to a negative value. And the error reads like

'0,-20,0,0' is not a valid value for property 'Margin'

code I am using :

```
parasignpic.Margin= new Thickness(0, -20, 0, 0);
```

Comment: try to delete the textblock and try it again, the code you are using works

Comment: this text block i create it in the run-time and put it in flowdocument

Comment: This maybe of interest, although I don't think it answers it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029987/set-property-margin-threw-an-exception

Comment: This has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769100/padding-margin-an-inline-flowdocument

Comment: @Dave Rook can you explain more thanks!

Comment: Don't use margin, use padding if you're using the control inside a flowDocument control.

Comment: @i was give the margin to the paragraph it self so it is not working it can't accept negative values :)